# Flash Develop weird behavior with autocomplete

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

Hey there quick question,

The auto-completion in FD started to do something weird.

Usually when you type

```
var position:Point
```

FD simply had the game.geom path in the Imports.

In one of my class when I type that it autocomplete with

```
var position:flash.geom.Point
```

everywhere. And does the same with the Rectangle class.

I had that kind of behavior when there was two classes with the same name (ambiguous call) but I don't have that problem here.

If someone have an idea ?

Many thanks

### EDIT

Found the issue ...

I had a variable called "flash"

```
var flash:Blink;
```

So ambiguous call indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen once when I added a swc to my project which had the same classes as the sdk which was setup for Flash Develop.

I would make sure you are not referencing any other swc or sdk which may have duplicates of these classes.

Failing that I'd probably backup my user settings and do a reinstall.

Comment: The weird thing is that it only happens in one class of the project. I checked all my libraries & file and I have no other Point class.

Comment: are you sure you don't have a duplicate import at the top of the class?

Comment: I search everywhere for another "Point" in the file and nothing. I'll try to re-install FD. Maybe I press a bad Key shortcut that I don't know of.

Comment: I had this happen when I had another "Point" in the include path not just the file. The compiler puts that there to make sure it has the right one.